# Getting Component in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, grid

I create a GridPanel like this:

```
grid = new xg.GridPanel({
    id: 'gridid',
    store: store,
    columns: [
    ...
```

Later on, I try to get the element so that I can load new data into it. In the Sencha Documentation it states that loadData is available to the GridPanel object

[image]

So I tried this:

```
Ext.getCmp('gridid').loadData(store);
```

And it chromes console prints this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'loadData'
```

Interestingly, when I try

```
Ext.getCmp('gridid').getStore().loadData(store);
```

This error goes away and the current store disappears from the grid, but it remains empty, the new store isn't loaded. Please help!

UPDATE: When I console.log the store I see all the information inside the object as it should appear, but its not being rendered in the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `store` that you're passing into the `loadData` function is not the same as the grid's store, try something like this:

```
var gridStore = Ext.getCmp('gridid').getStore();
gridStore.removeAll();
gridStore.add(store.getRange());
```

Answer (score 1):

my Ext is a bit rusty but I'm pretty sure loadData is passed the data itself (e.g. an array of records/objects), not the store.

How did you declare your store? is it loading remote data or static local data?

There is an example of using loadData here: http://extjs.wima.co.uk/example/4

If you're using remote data, maybe you're just missing autoload on your store declaration..